# JavaScript function to query a MS Access DB using Recordsets with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, sql, database, select, adodb

I have a front-end HTML page which is querying an MS Access Database.

HTML:

```
<input class="textbox" id="searchValue" maxlength="100" name="KeywordSearch" onclick="this.value='';" size="50" type="text" value="Enter Your Keyword Here" />

<input class="textbox" id="ForCLNo" name="CLNum"  type="text" onclick="this.value='';" size="25" type="text" value="CL Number"/> 

<input class="button" name="Search" onclick="searchEngineSearch();" type="button" value="Search" /></p>
```

Want to execute this query:

```
SELECT * FROM MasterTable where CLNo = test1 AND Query = test2;
```

For the query, `SELECT * FROM MasterTable where Query LIKE test2`, I have created the ADODB object as follows:

```
var adVarWChar = 202;
var adParamInput = 1;
var pad = "C:\\Users\\Rik\\Desktop\\Project\\MyTable.accdb";
var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pad;
cn.Open(strConn);
var cm = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");
cm.ActiveConnection = cn;

cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MasterTable where Query LIKE test2";

cm.Parameters.Append(cm.CreateParameter(
        "test2",
        adVarWChar,
        adParamInput,
        255,
        "%" + document.getElementById("searchValue").value + "%"));
var rs = cm.Execute();
```

and the correct result is obtained.

Not sure how to rewrite the cm.Parameters.Append(cm.CreateParameter()) function to incorporate more than one WHERE condition in an SQL query [`SELECT * FROM MasterTable where CLNo = test1 AND Query = test2;`].

Please Help :)

Comment: Tried by adding cm.Parameters(0) = test1; and cm.Parameters(1) = test2; Not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating one parameter within the Parameters collection already... you just need to create one more:

```
cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MasterTable where Query LIKE test1 OR Query LIKE Test2";

cm.Parameters.Append(cm.CreateParameter(
    "test1",
    adVarWChar,
    adParamInput,
    255,
    "%" + document.getElementById("searchValue").value + "%"));


cm.Parameters.Append(cm.CreateParameter(
    "test2",
    adVarWChar,
    adParamInput,
    255,
    "%" + document.getElementById("searchValue").value + "%"));

var rs = cm.Execute();
```

`cm.Parameters` is a collection, meaning it's capable of holding any reasonable number of its item type.  For each piece of parameter code above, you append a newly created parameter into the collection. The entire collection is then used to resolve the SQL statement.